# The adjectives well-off and well-to-do: Is there a fine difference between them?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

On the dictionary com. site, the adjective [*well-off*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/well-off) is defined as "having sufficient money for a comfortable living; well-to-do".

At the same time, the adjective [*well-to-do*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/well-to-do) is defined there as "prosperous; rich" (without mentioning well-off).  As for the synonyms of each ([1](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/well-off), [2](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/well-to-do)) of the two, although they are  *almost* the same, but there's a slight difference in their relevance for the one or the other.

Does this mean that anything/anyone which/who is well-off is also well-to-do, but not vice versa? Is there a fine difference between the two in usage?

Could there be a situation when the choice was to be made in favor of the one and not of the other?

Comment: They're both a bit colloquial. The only real difference is that ***well-to-do*** is relatively dated / literary, so you should probably avoid it unless you *want* to sound a bit old-fashioned and "posh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking through dictionaries trying to corroborate my personal (UK-based) understanding of these terms.

Both certainly imply a degree of prosperity, but neither I think imply that person is very rich; say millionaires not billionaires.

I would agree with FumbleFingers that both are somewhat colloquial, and that **well-to-do** is rather dated; the biography of P.L.Travers (the author of Mary Poppins) describes her remembering her father as **well-to-do**.

I have always though of **well-off** as describing the financial status of a person. The Free Dictionary says **moderately rich**.

On the other hand I have thought of **well-to-do** being as much concerned with the outward behaviour arising from that wealth. Such a person not only has money but uses it to buy possessions, often those that increase their social standing.

The Collins dictionary gives this example:

> In the seat in front of him a well-to-do matron and her paunchy husband were busy adjusting an expensive camcorder.
>   Pacter, Trudi YELLOW BIRD

Note that the matron (woman) herself is described as well-to-do, and we immediately think of someone very well dressed.

This distinction is not clear in the dictionaries I have consulted, but I do think is implicit in the actual terms themselves. It would not, in my opinion, give the same impression to say

> a well-off matron